# Compile OpenBroadcaster on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, compiling

Trying to compile obs on debian like here described: https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/INSTALL
gives me this error:

```
Linking C shared library libobs.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/../lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libobs/CMakeFiles/libobs.dir/build.make:1591: recipe for target 'libobs/libobs.so.0' failed
make[2]: *** [libobs/libobs.so.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:333: recipe for target 'libobs/CMakeFiles/libobs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libobs/CMakeFiles/libobs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I already tried compiling it with `-fPIC` but that gave me this error:

```
make: PIC: File or Directory not found
make: *** No rule to make target 'PIC'. stop.
```

Comment: It doesn't mean running `make -fPIC`.  `-fPIC` is an option for gcc.  Probably you failed to build your `libavcodec.a` in ffmpeg with the shared library support.  Have you set up your ffmpeg build with `configure --enable-shared`?

Comment: no but I'll do this now.

Comment: @yaegashi Is not working too. http://pastebin.com/6SVhPnYr

Comment: Does any of non-PIC binaries you previously built still remain in your source dirs and/or `/usr/local/lib`?  Clean them out and build everything again from the beginning, i.e. extracting sources out of the archive.

Comment: doesn't look like http://pastebin.com/M1cdi3gP

Comment: Then what did you get from `cmake` in ops-studio build?  Could you paste full output of it?  You should have seen something like `-- Found FFMpeg: /usr/local/lib/../lib/libavformat.so`.  Make sure to repeat procedure from the beginning with `git clone`.

Comment: Yeah there is: http://pastebin.com/sie8xWTc

Comment: `-- Found FFMpeg: /usr/local/lib/../lib/libavformat.a` that's your problem.  `cmake` chose a static library to link.  And it seems you failed to do it from the beginning, because you showed me cached output of `cmake`.  Wipe out all of obs-studio source/build dirs you have and try again.

Comment: Did but nothing has been changed.

Comment: You have to investigate by yourself why `cmake` on your system chooses static libraries (`.a`) over shared libraries (`.so`).  It's opposite to the common behavior of `cmake`.  Removing `/usr/local/lib/lib*.a` before running `cmake` might bring you a new clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed this guide here then it worked: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu